# Is it possible to call a Restful web service from an EJB2 client

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, ejb

I have been looking around for examples of how to call a Restful service written in Spring 3 from an EJB2 client. If i understand REST correctly, it should not matter what technology/language the service is written in so i should be able to call the service from an EJB2 client.

I couldn't find a simple example or reference to guide me on how to implement an EJB2 client that can call a restful service. Does this mean that is not possible to call a Restful service from an EJB2 client? If it is possible, could you please point me to a document or example that shows or describe how the two can interface/talk to each other.

Most of the references/documentation i come across are related to how to expose an EJB as a web service whereas i am interested in how to call a web service from an EJB2.

I am particularly interested in how i can send an XML document to the service. For example, is it possible to use a Jersey client and JAXB with EJB2 and how would i pass the unmarshalled XML over HTTP using EJB2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An EJB2 client is just like any other Java client, so...

Comment: if you can make http call...u can call REST service as well.

Comment: I know that i can make an HTTP call to call the Rest service. Is it possible though to use a client like Jersey with JAXB within an EJB 2 to call the REST service?

Comment: @ziggy: why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are a couple of programmatic options for accessing a RESTful service in Java.

**Using JDK/JRE APIs**

Below is an example of calling a RESTful service using the APIs in the JDK/JRE

```
String uri =
    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers/1";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
Customer customer =
    (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

connection.disconnect();
```

**Using Jersey APIs**

Most JAX-RS implementations include APIs that make accessing RESTful services easier.   A client API is being included in the JAX-RS 2 specification.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.example.Customer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;

public class JerseyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers");

        // Get response as String
        String string = resource.path("1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .get(String.class);
        System.out.println(string);

        // Get response as Customer
        Customer customer = resource.path("1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .get(Customer.class);
        System.out.println(customer.getLastName() + ", "+ customer.getFirstName());

        // Get response as List<Customer>
        List<Customer> customers = resource.path("findCustomersByCity/Any%20Town")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .get(new GenericType<List<Customer>>(){});
        System.out.println(customers.size());
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise. The above example show how to receive an XML/Jersey paylod. If possible could you show an example of the data going out the other way. i.e. The client posting an XML/Jersey payload to the REST service.